# Doctrine: how to skip empty/null columns at persisting data

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine

I do have a Repository like this

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity()
* @ORM\Table(name="user_data")App\Models
*/
class UserData{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   protected $id;
   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   protected $email;
   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, options={"default":""})
    */
   protected $telephone = '';
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTelephone()
    {
        return $this->telephone;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $telephone
     */
    public function setTelephone($telephone)
    {
        $this->telephone = $telephone;
    }
}
```

and i do have this code part to create a user

```
$user = new UserData();
$user->setEmail( $user_data['email'] );
App::DB()->persist($user);
App::DB()->flush();
```

where App::DB() contains my enitymanager

if i execute the code above i get the following error

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user_data (email, telephone) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [&quot;qwe@qwe.qwe&quot;, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'telephone' cannot be null
```

i know, that i can set give a default value to the protected $telephone, but how can i tell doctrine to either use the default values from the ORM\Column or better better to ignore the 'empty' fields in the query building process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Introduction

I had an almost similar problem before and I was able to solve my problem using [Lifecycle Callbacks](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html). Since I am not very experienced with Symfony, I will first explain my problem and my solution, then will cope with yours in this answer.

#### My problem

I had a `NewsletterItem` entity and I needed to create a `hash` for it, which was dependent of the `id`, so I needed to set the value of `hash` after the record has been created. I know you will need to execute something before the record is being created, but bear with me for a few minutes, I think it will be a time well spent from your part, as I would have been happy to see some previous experience when I was in your situation, having an almost similar problem.

#### My solution

1. I have been using `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM`:

   `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`
2. I specified that the entity has lifecycle callbacks:

   ```
    /**
    * ...
    * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
    */
   ```

   `class NewsletterItem implements \Serializable
   {`
3. I have made sure that I have a method which initializes the `hash`:

`private function calculateHash()
    {
        //Here I set the hash based on id, among others and return it
    }`

4. I implemented `setHash` and made sure it will be called after the entity is being created:

`/**
     * Set hash
     *
     * @ORM\PostPersist
     * @return NewsletterItem
     */
    public function setHash()
    {
        $this->calculateHash();
        return $this;
    }`

5. I cleared the cache of the application

and then everything worked like a charm

#### Your solution

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity()
* @ORM\Table(name="user_data")App\Models
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class UserData{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   protected $id;
   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
   protected $email;
   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, options={"default":""})
    */
   protected $telephone = '';
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTelephone()
    {
        return $this->telephone;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @param mixed $telephone
     */
    public function setTelephone($telephone)
    {
        $this->telephone = ($telephone ? $telephone : '');
    }
}
```

I have never tried out what I am suggesting to you, so if it is not working, then you might need an `initializeTelephone` method specifically for this purpose.

Comment: thanks in advance, i will take a look into this and 'lifecycle callbacks' and report back :)

Comment: i've read some stuff about lifecycle callback (which are new to me and might come in handy in the future), but i think they don't solve my problem. i dont want to define a function for each column (for that i can simply use 'protected $colum = 'default value'). I want to make doctrine automatically using the 'options={"default":""}' i gave him at the ORM line, but thanks for the lifecycle callback 'hint' as i said, might be useful for other problems

Comment: @bob you do not need to define a function for each column. You can define a single function where everything you need to be handled before persisting the entity will be handled.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the nullable property can help? You won't have to provide a default value and it will persist